# Insert JavaScript into WebView before pageload

Tags: javascript, json, webview

I have a little problem while inserting JavaScript into my WebView before the page is loaded.

The reason why I want to insert JavaScript ist because I can't pass JSON to Java via a JavascriptInterface. I don't want to use strings or JSON.stringify while developing the WebApps so my approach was to add some JavaScript inside the WebViewClient.onPageStarted() method.

simplified example:

```
var JSWrapper = {
  callJavascriptInterface: function (str, obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
      JavascriptInterface.function(str, JSON.stringify(obj));
    } else {
      JavascriptInterface.function(str);
    }
  }
}
```

inside onPageStarted I also unregister sensors and remove old callbacks I registered via JavascriptInterfaces, cause they should be enabled anymore when the site has changed.

That works when I change the site via a link or something but if I use window.location.reload() I end up with errors (JSWrapper not defined).

Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem or maybe even a better approach for turning off the sensors, removing callbacks and the JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 0):

`onPageStarted` is not a good place for doing anything with the page. It is called right after the moment when the first reply has been obtained from the server, and may happen before the page has been actually processed by the rendering engine. Thus, depending on the speed of page loading, you might end up interacting with the previously loaded page, which will be discarded (together with your changes) soon.

Another point to keep in mind is that changes to Java interfaces injected / removed via `add/removeJavascriptInterface` only affect the next loaded page. That is, after you, say, added a new Java interface, you must do a page (re)load in order to make this interface actually available to the page. If you try to change injected interfaces configuration from `onPageStarted`, this again may or may not affect the page you are loading.

So if you want to do a cleanup, or prepare for navigating to a new page, it's better to use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, because it is called after the page has decided to navigate, but before any loading has started (just remember to return `false` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` so loading proceeds as usual).

If you want to modify freshly loaded page, e.g. insert your JavaScript code, use `onPageFinished` -- it is called after the resources of the new page have been loaded and parsed. But remember that it's too late to inject Java interfaces at this point, as they will only affect next loaded page.